# Volume and relativity -- how it affects properties of an object?

Tags: special-relativity

My understanding is that the dimensions of objects change relative to an observer so that a moving cube would no longer be cube shaped and its volume might differ.

However, what if that object was absorbing radiation based on its surface area: would a stationary observer see a different amount of heating than a person within the cube? And would this be a paradox?

Comment: You need to Lorentz-transform the radiation too.